# Z Notation: sequence of sequences - find sum

Tags: formal-methods, z-notation

Let me just say that this is for a university project. I do not expect an answer but more of a "hint".

I have a schema of a Supermarket that holds a sequence of queues:

```
+-- Supermarket-------
|queues: seq Queue
----------------------
```

And here is how I've defined a queue:

```
+-- Queue ----------
|length: ℕ
--------------------
```

I wish to define a schema that returns the total number of customers, waiting in line. Thus far I have:

```
+--TotalQueueCustomers----
|Ξsupermarket: Supermarket
|totalCustomers!: ℕ
|-------------------------
|totalCustomers = total θ supermarket
--------------------------
```

I'm struggling with defining the `total` function. It needs to "loop" every customer in every queue and sum their `length`s. Here is what I have so far: `total = q: Queue ⦁ q.length ↦ q.length`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function inductively by having a base case (no queues) and specifying how an additional queue is computed:

```
total: seq Queue → ℕ
---
total(∅) = 0
∀ q: Queue; qs: seq Queue ⦁ total( <q> ^ qs ) = q.length + total(qs)
```

`<q>` is the sequence having a single element `q`, `a ^ b` denotes the sequence concatenation operator (Section 4.5 of the Z reference manual).

(Please note: I did not check this example with a Z type checker, so it probably contains some kind of syntax error - but the idea should be clear)